# Javascript/React fetch api sending image via formdata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to send a file object (image) as a multipart/form-data request using the javascript fetch api.
The code below shows how I convert the file object to string format.
The image parameter is an array of File objects. I want to send the first image of that array to a webservice.

```
onImageUpload = ((image) => {
 //File to arraybuffer
 let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(e) {
    var text = e.target.result;
    AccountService.uploadProfileImage(localStorage.getItem('session-key'), text)
  .then((ro) => {
    if(ro.code == 200) {
      this.showSnackbar("Profile image uploaded successfully!");
    }
    else {
      this.showSnackbar("Error uploading your image. Please try again later.");
    }
  })
}
 fr.readAsText(image[0]);
})
```

Below is my uploadProfileImage function, which makes the post request using the fetch api.

```
static async uploadProfileImage(sessionKey, image) {
var reader  = new FileReader();
let ro = new ResponseObject();
let fd = new FormData();
let imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = image;
let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(image)], { type: "image/jpg"});
fd.append("name", localStorage.getItem('username'));
fd.append("file", blob);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(UrlConstants.BASE_URL + this.urlUploadProfileImage, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionKey,
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data;"
    },
    body: fd
  }).then((response) => {
    ro.code = response.status;
    return response.text();
  })
  .then((text) => {
    ro.message = text;
    resolve(ro);
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    reject(ex);
  })
});
}
```

When I sent the image parameter in the uploadProfileImage without converting it into a blob the data are being sent, but i need the blob to have the Content-Type: "image/jpg" in the request as the api I'm working with can't handle the request without it.
The problem that the image is not being included in the request.

How can I do that?
Thanks for your help.